# Strange Variation on Euclid's Game

Tags: game-theory, puzzle, euclidean-algorithm

I came across some instructions for Euclid's Game which I don't think are correct:

> Euclid’s game starts with two unequal positive numbers
> on the board. Two players move in turn. On each move, a player has
> to write on the board a positive number equal to the difference of two
> numbers already on the board; this number must be new, i.e., different
> from all the numbers already on the board. The player who cannot move
> loses the game. Should you choose to move first or second in this game?

The reason I don't think this is correct is that all other versions I've seen described claim that a multiple of one of the numbers should be subtracted from the other. Then the game repeats with just the two numbers remaining after this step. This makes the game mimic Euclid's Algorithm, which makes the name make sense.

The version given seems to end only when all numbers from 1 to the highest number have been listed.

For example:

Start: $1, 5$

player $1$ chooses $5, 1:$

$$1, 5, 4$$

player $2$ chooses $4, 1:$

$$1, 5, 4, 3$$

player $1$ chooses $5, 3:$

$$1, 5, 4, 3, 2$$

player $2$ loses as no new positive number can be made by subtraction.

What I'd like to know is:

Have I misunderstood the rules?

Are the rules incorrect for what is usually called "Euclid's Game?"

Will this version always produce numbers from 1 to the higher original number (or multiples of 10, 100 etc. up to the highest number) and if so, why?

Comment: Try it with $p=200, q =30$, and look at the results.

Comment: Good point. I've made a small edit to account for these kinds of cases.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really get to the heart of the problem. Try for example p=15, q=21.

Comment: If the GCD is 1, all numbers between 1 and the highest number will appear, otherwise no more subtractions can be made once the GCD is reached?

Comment: I think it's important for comprehensive understanding to try to answer the question posed by the problem: should you choose to move 1st or 2nd and why?

Comment: for the example p=15, q=21 (GCD is 3) then 3 appears before 18 so it is not the case that no more subtractions can be made once the GCD is reached.  That isn't the case for p=1, q=5 either.

Comment: Can you break it down into steps?  
Firstly, can you see why the gcd will eventually appear?  Then, if you know it does appear, what other numbers beside p and q and their gcd can also appear?  Finally, what's the maximum count of numbers that can appear (and does it matter which choices player 1 and player 2 make on the way, in other words, is it possible to make a mistake in playing?).  Can you answer the question based on that? 
Alternatively, if you already knew how many numbers could appear, could you decide whether to play first or second based on that?

Comment: To answer _your_ question (rather than the one posed by the original puzzle): no, the rules are not wrong, they are consistent with the name of the game.